# Creating Multiple instances when i open the Google Chrome browser in Windows Operating System

Tags: windows, google-chrome

> Multiple instances are created and running in background when i open
>   the **google chrome browser** as shown below.Any alternative solution
>   to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Not only does every tab in Chrome run in its own process but they separate multiple other things into their own process as well. Each of these processes are sandboxed for security.